# iOS - Is UITableViewCellDelegate Necessary When I Have Helper Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegation

I've been taught to always use delegates for `UITableViewCell`, but I already have a helper class called `MyDefaults` that handles getting and setting certain preferences to `NSUserDefaults`.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

In my `DummyPreferenceCell.h`:

```
@protocol DummyPreferenceCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)setDefaultDummyPreferenceTo:(NSString *)dummyPreferenceOption;

@end
```

In my `DummyPreferenceCell.m`:

```
- (IBAction)dummyPreferenceOptionSelected:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSString *dummyPreferenceOption = @"";
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        // first dummy preference option selected
        case 0:
            dummyPreferenceOption = @"dummyOption1";
            break;

        // second dummy preference option selected    
        case 1:
            dummyPreferenceOption = @"dummyOption2";
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
            return;
            break;
    }
    [self.delegate setDefaultDummyPreferenceTo:dummyPreferenceOption];
}
```

In my parent `ViewController.m`:

```
#pragma mark - DummyPreferenceCellDelegate

-(void)setDefaultDummyPreferenceTo:(NSString *)dummyPreferenceOption {
    [MyDefaults setDummyPreferenceTo:dummyPreferenceOption];
}
```

Is delegation necessary when I already have a helper class to do the action for me, or will it cause future problems if I don't use delegation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following MVC pattern.

> `DummyPreferenceCell` extends `UITableViewCell` which is just part of being View of the Modal View Controller paradigm
>
> In MVC , the View isnt assigned responsibility to manage the data.
>   that is what the model does. so it is infact correct to pass back the
>   selection to the controller which will pass it to the model and then
>   you can do all validations there

Comment: Thanks! Even though it looks a little redundant, I guess I'll keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the event in ViewController of when UISegmentedControl value change you need to write delegate otherwise you can store it in your helper class. whenever you write delegate it should be.

```
- (IBAction)dummyPreferenceOptionSelected:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSString *dummyPreferenceOption = @"";
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        // first dummy preference option selected
        case 0:
            dummyPreferenceOption = @"dummyOption1";
            break;

        // second dummy preference option selected    
        case 1:
            dummyPreferenceOption = @"dummyOption2";
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
            return;
            break;
    }
   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setDefaultDummyPreferenceTo:) ])
    [self.delegate setDefaultDummyPreferenceTo:dummyPreferenceOption];
}
```

hope this helps